# How to autofill column based on Serial Primary Key in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns like:

```
inner_id(serial pk) | id(varchar) | name(varchar) | fid(varchar)
```

I want to send row with only id and name: (id, name)
How can I say to Postgresql to complete 'fid' column with value based in serial pk(like string + primary key)?
I want this kind of output:

```
inner_id(serial pk) | id(varchar) | name(varchar) | fid(varchar)
         1               G786k          NAME           FID-1
         2               l7hk           NAME           FID-2
```

AS a bonus I send row from python and have to use %s in query

UPD.
I tried run query like:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, fid)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s||TO_CHAR(inner_id));
```

But I get an error, that i cannot refer to inner_id(primary key)

Comment: Postgres 12 introduces computed columns.  I would recommend simply doing this using a view.

Comment: Why store the same information twice? This is much better done when you select the data. Or create a view as Gordon suggested

Comment: Well, I need this for my current solution of existing problem! And currently search info about computed columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your inner_id is a sequence, you can get the name of the sequence and use [Nextval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-sequence.html)

So it should be something like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE ("id","name","fid")
VALUES (your_id, 'some_name', 'FID-' || nextval('your_sequence_id') - 1);
```

Comment: Does not work. There is error that i cant refer primary key. ...VALUES (%s,%s,%s||curval(inner_id));

Comment: It's not inner id that you need to use but the inner_id sequence. PostgreSQL generates a sequence when you use a serial

Comment: Could you, please, clarify. I don't understand how to call sequence but not column 'inner id'. Is inner_id sequence generated by postgresql is different from column inner_id

Comment: I guess i've found sequences in pgAdmin.

Comment: Well, thank you! Your decision works good enough for me for now.

Comment: Note that you could also use curval instead of nextval

Answer (score 0):

If you define inner_id as 'serial' Postgres will generate sequence for it. Generally something like "table_name_column_name-seq". You can then set the default for the "fid" column using the currval of that sequence.

```
create table soq.ref_to_id( inner_id serial, id text, name text, fid text);

alter table soq.ref_to_id alter column fid set default 'FID-' || currval('soq.ref_to_id_inner_id_seq')::text;

-- insert tast data    
insert into soq.ref_to_id(id, name)  
   values ('G786k', 'Gname')
        , ('17hk',  '17NAME');  

-- check results  
select * from soq.ref_to_id;
```